# Display the saved data in my dropdown list

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a dropdown list which I display all the data that I have in my database in a specific table.
Now I want to display first a data from another table of my database, to be more specific I want to display first in my dropdown list the column specialty from the table doctor.
How can I do that?

Below is the code in order to display the data from another table in my database:

```
    <label id="Specialty">Specialty:</label>
    <select id="SelectSpecialty" name="specialty">
    <?php
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM specialties");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
  }
?>
```

PS: I want to display both datas from the two tables in the dropdown list

Comment: What's your db schema?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to do an union of the both table datas.

```
select *
 from (
    select name, 1 as seq from specialties
    union
    select name, 2 as seq from specialties2
 ) a order by a.seq;
```

Note that if you already know both tables won't have duplicate values, it would be better to use `UNION ALL` as it is more performant because it does not check for duplicates.

Notice the hardcoded `seq` to make sure the result set from first table goes to the top.

Comment: If i make it like that .... $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM specialties UNION ALL SELECT specialty FROM doctor WHERE username='$username'"); ... then it shows me the data that I want but it display the data that I want first, last

Comment: @niklakis Use the query I posted with the seq and order by.

Comment: @niklakis any feedback on this ?